# -swipeWithEvent: not called until a two-finger scroll occurs

Tags: cocoa, nsview, gestures, nsresponder

I have a `NSView` subclass inside an `NSScrollView` that implements `-swipeWithEvent`. I've noticed that `swipeWithEvent:` is never called until the user first performs a two-finger scroll on the trackpad. After that, it works consistently. What could possibly cause this?

Comment: I know swipeWithEvent: will get sent to the first responder.  Maybe scrolling affects the responder chain?

Comment: Looks similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433120/nsresponder-swipewithevent-not-called